# Is a JSP a servlet?

Tags: java, jsp

today an intersting debate rose about the following proposition:
"A JSP IS A SERVLET"

Do you guys think this sentence is formally acceptable?

thanks in advance,

chris

Comment: I'd say so. It's primary function is to make it easy to create a web page which can be converted into a Servlet

Comment: This should not be a debate, a debate is where there is minimum understanding to both concepts, a deep relation and coherence, not here, simply go and learn each one of them.

Comment: It's more of a linguistic question, which depends on the definition of *is*. It's like *"A GIF is a picture"*. Since JSP can be seen as a representation of servlet, and each JSP is mapped to a servlet, *"A JSP is a servlet"* can be understood to be true. For engineering purpose, we do separate the two concepts, since it's very different how we work with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `JSP` is NOT a servlet.

However the container like Tomcat use Jasper engine to compile a JSP into a `servlet` class.

Answer (score 1):

The question is formally acceptable but the answer is "not it isn't".

A `jsp` or (Java Server Page) is a dinamically generated web page, while a `servlet` is an implementation of a server feature.

So they are really different from each others.

Answer (score 1):

JSP pages translated to Servlet classes when your war file is deployed to the servlet container.

See this page for an example:
http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/WWW/jsp/translation.html

Answer (score 0):

No, JSP is not a servlet. Servlet is basically a Java class that run on a server. When client requests a JSP page, then on the server, JSP engine compiles the JSP into a Servlet. And then the generated servlet is compiled into Java class and this java class service the request and send response to the client.